# Android Wear Close Bitmap Asset Underlying Stream

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have code that creates a `PutDataRequest` to sync a `Bitmap` with a wearable. My question is, do I need to close the `ByteArrayOutputStream` in the code below, or does the `DatApi` need it to stay open?

I'm pretty sure it needs to be closed. Just having a brain-fart moment.

```
PutDataMapRequest putRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
DataMap map = putRequest.getDataMap();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Asset asset = Asset.createFromBytes(stream.toByteArray());
map.putAsset(mapKey, asset);

Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(connection.getClient(), putRequest.asPutDataRequest());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at this line:

```
Asset asset = Asset.createFromBytes(stream.toByteArray());
```

it's clear that the Asset instance has no reference to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, since it received a reference to the `byte[]`, not to the stream itself.  So you should be able to close it safely after that point.

For safety, however, you could `flush()` the stream before calling `toByteArray()`, in case `compress()` does not do that already.